# Trusted Sites IE 7 problem

Tags: internet-explorer-7

I have links which are pointing to a javascript method. The javascript method call some ajax logic and decides which file to download. If i add my site URL into trusted sites clicking on these links shows up a yellow bar as a warning which then allows me to download the file. Can anyone suggest how to avoid that yellow bar. Or whats the reason behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change it to a custom setting, even trusted sites disables automatic download. Look in the security settings under Download -> Automatic prompting for file downloads, and change it to Enable. Disable means you get the bar. Changing the security level to Low also does this.

It's a security mechanism to prevent unexpected drive-by downloads in sites, even trusted ones.